# ExpertSystem Error prolog

Tags: prolog, system

I have the clam.pl and the car.ckb, I need to run the expert system taken from amzi. I want to run my project on SWI PROLOG, so I write :

`super.` to launch the interpreter

`load"`   to load the data

`'car.ckb'.` input the specific file

but the output is :

`ghoul(problem)
rule 1
rule 2
rule 3
rule 4
rule 5
rule 6
output battery
output out_of_gas
output flooded
askable turn_over
askable lights_weak
askable radio_weak
askable smell_gas
askable gas_gauge`

The system doesn't ask me any questions and seems to crash after the last answer! Why ? 
Does anyone a good clam.pl file or similar ? I need one with a good cf handling !

clam.pl is [Here](https://github.com/Anniepoo/amziexpertsystemsinprolog/blob/master/clam.pl)

car.ckb is [Here](https://github.com/Anniepoo/amziexpertsystemsinprolog/blob/master/car.ckb)

Comment: what is a `good cf handling` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is going to help with your question (I have little time now), but Anniepoo stated this commit comment on `clam.pl`

> cleaned up many non SWI-Prolog bits. Still needs output/3 defined

So, is output/3 properly defined in your downloaded source ?

*edit*

You can read [the book](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/SS09/KI/folien/merritt.pdf) from where these examples are taken, to get a working knowledge about this topic...  beware, there could be bugs in the listings. For instance, I've built an enhanced 'native shell' and I had to correct a bug in the inference engine... but I refer to the book' listings, indeed I was unaware of the availability of these resources. Thanks @Anniepoo for making these (again) available to wider audience.

As a general remark, I would say that an Expert System Shell is a difficult theme is you are still learning the basics of Prolog... you really should start from the simpler one, i.e. the native shell (birds.ncb)

Comment: No, is the original file ...yes I know, poor me. When I said "a good cf handling" I meant an Inference engine with certainty factor (cf) like Mycin. I plumbed every site, maybe 60% of all internet ( sad but true ) but there is nothing, the only thing i understand is this : cf = cf(rule)*cf(fact)/100 ... but nothing about a working example for swi prolog . Can you Help me ?